# Cannot login to MySQL from localhost with Host set to %

Tags: mysql, localhost, xampp

I installed XAMPP 5.5.24 and created a DB for my application and a MySQL user to connect to it. However, I was facing the following problem:

The user was not able to locally connect MySQL while having the `Host` column in the `mysql.user` table set to `%` until I granted access from `localhost` explicitly.

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user order by user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
|                  | localhost |
|                  | linux     |
| myNewUser        | %         |
| myNewUser        | localhost |
| pma              | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| root             | linux     |
+------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I’ve thought `%` in the `Host` column should allow everything, including `localhost`. However, without the line `| myNewUser        | localhost |`, MySQL refuses any local connection (tried `-h localhost`, `127.0.0.1`) until specifying the LAN IP address.

```
iMac:www Mirek$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u myNewUser -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myNewUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
iMac:www Mirek$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u myNewUser -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myNewUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
iMac:www Mirek$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u myNewUser -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myNewUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
iMac:www Mirek$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u myNewUser -p -h 10.0.1.2
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 133
Server version: 5.6.24 Source distribution
```

Is this the normal behavior? Or am I missing something?

Comment: mysql localhost connections go through a socket, not via a tcp connection. They're special in that regard and because of that they don't match the `%` host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@wurtel](https://superuser.com/users/365297/wurtel) mentioned, the connection to `localhost` bypasses TCP using a UNIX socket file and therefore is not matching any TCP address (`%`).

Reference:
[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual — 5.2.2 Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you login via TCP/IP, you need to specify port and protocol

```
mysql -u myNewUser -p -h 10.0.1.2 -p3306 --protocol=tcp
```

Then, it should work.

To verify, when you login, run this

```
mysql> SELECT USER() AttemptedToLoginAs,CURRENT_USER() MySQLAllowedMeAs;
```

If `AttemptedToLoginAs` and `MySQLAllowedMeAs` both say `myNewUser@%`, you did it right.